# Regex replace to reorder text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a page which needs to output text from a DB, this text will sometimes have one or more videos embeded via iframe. I need to output this so the videos are displayed down the left of the text (Via css floating) - although this requires the video to be placed before the text.

At the moment I have this

```
$text = preg_replace("#(.*?)(<iframe.*?</iframe>)(.*?)#i", '$2 $1 $3', $text);
```

However this will only move the first iframe if more than one is present, leaving the others where they were.

Example In:

```
abcdefghijkl
<iframe....></iframe>
mnopqrstuvwxyz
<iframe....></iframe>
```

Desired Out:

```
<iframe....></iframe>
<iframe....></iframe>
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: you only have 2 iframes?

Comment: the number of frames is unknown; one frame is most common but there could be 2+ iframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use preg_replace_callback to do such thing here's an example but you will be using globals which is really a dirty solution:

```
$str = 'abcdefghijkl
<iframe....></iframe>
mnopqrstuvwxyz
<iframe....></iframe>';

global $myText;
global $myIframe;

preg_replace_callback("/([^<]+)(<iframe[^>]+>[^<]*<\/iframe>)/i",
            function($matches) use ($myText) {
                    global $myText, $myIframe;
                    $myText .= $matches[1];
                    $myIframe .= $matches[2]; 

            },
            $str);

echo $myIframe."<br>".$myText;
```

Comment: I had to alter it slightly as the text can include some html tags which the ([^<]+) doesn't seem to like - so I just changed it to (.*?) but apart from that works great - Cheers

Comment: Instead of those global variables, you could use `function($matches) use (&$myText, &$myIframe) {` :)